# Change comma to dot, working with decimals in php

Tags: php

So i have some fields coming from the form. Here you can type 0.3 and it will insert 0.3 in to the database. Do you type 0,3 it will just insert "0".

```
$product['protein']; // 0,3
```

So to this above how can i replace a comma with a dot ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try PHP's function [str_replace()](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$product['protein'] = str_replace(',', '.', $product['protein']);
```

Which should be a good fit.

You could think to use [number_format()](http://php.net/number_format):

```
number_format($value, $numberOfDecimals, $charaForDecimalPoint, $charForThousandsSeparator)
```

but in your case it wouldn't apply, due to the fact that your starting value ("0,3") wouldn't be recognized as a number.
In fact, the decimal point for a numeric value must be a dot(".").

Use number_format only if your starting value is a true number.

Comment: It's a problem when people/machines start to enter numbers with thousand separators such as 1.337,42 - a problem I actually faced the resulting value is 1.333742 in php - a factor 1000 wrong.

Comment: this answer does not handle numbers like `1.2345,67`

Answer (score 5):

```
$product['protein'] = str_replace(",",".",$product['protein'])
```

For more info on the str_replace function visit: http://uk.php.net/str_replace

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$product['protein'] = str_replace(",",".",$product['protein'])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$product['protein'] = str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $product['protein']));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer