# Change . (point) sparator to , (comma) on input type='number' in html5

Tags: html

how to change `.` to `,` on `input type='number'` in html5, couse in my country for fraction use `,` not `.` . i'll process it into .php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**OPTION 1**. use `<input type="number" lang="en" value="13.5">` if you want `.` , and if you want `,` (comma) use `lang="your-language"` . and it will change automatically to a comma

*BROWSER SUPPORT* : this is not supported in every browser ( Chrome doesn't support it, Mozzila FF does. ) . so you might want to use another solution

see here more about this solution :**[lang input[type="number]](https://www.slightfuture.com/webdev/html5-input-number-localization)**

see snippet:

```html
<input type="number" lang="en" value="13.5">
<input type="number" lang="ro" value="13.5">
```

**OPTION 2**

you could use the php function `str_replace()` see more here > **[str_replace()](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)**

or other similar SO questions > [replace dot with comma1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740233/how-to-replace-dot-with-comma-in-price-format-in-php) and [replace dot with comma2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461459/change-comma-to-dot-working-with-decimals-in-php)

Comment: i think i like used the option 2, couse option 1 doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There is no sollution that works with all browsers.
I'd personally use `str_replace(',', '.', $magical_number);` since it adds support to use both.

Answer (score -2):

Be more explanative on the question,

```
 <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```

where do you want to add comma here. Paste a sample code.

In PHP you can use `implode(',',$variable)` or `str_replace('.',',',$variable)`.